# Select query with names columns

Tags: sql, oracle10g, rdbms

I want have a query on the table  values

```
Column1 Column2 Column3   
-----------------------
a         b      c    
d         e      f
```

Result should be

```
Column1 a
Column2 b
Column3 c
Column1 d
Column2 e
Column3 f
```

Basically a key value pairs. Is it possible in Oracle?

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Randy that is actually an `unpivot` not `pivot`

Comment: njk, if you cant answer dont waste my time please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `UNION ALL`, like this:

```
SELECT 'Column1' as Name, Column1 as Value FROM my_table
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Column2' as Name, Column2 as Value FROM my_table
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Column3' as Name, Column3 as Value FROM my_table
```

[Here is a demo on sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bc512/1).

Comment: ok thanks, what if the table has 100 columns, basically idea is to supply a key value pair end client, also the query needs to be efficient.